# Pandas groupby apply a random day to each group of years

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to generate a different random day within each year group of a dataframe. So I need `replacement = False`, otherwise it will fail.

You can't just add a column of random numbers because **I'm going to have more than 365 years in my list of years** and once you hit 365 it can't create any more random samples without replacement.

I have explored agg, aggreagte, apply and transform. The closest I have got is with this:

```
    years = pd.DataFrame({"year": [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4]})
    years["day"] = 0
    grouped = years.groupby("year")["day"]
    grouped.transform(lambda x: np.random.choice(366, replace=False))
```

Which gives this:

```
0       8
1       8
2     319
3     319
4     319
5     149
6     149
7     130
8     130
9     130
10    130
Name: day, dtype: int64
```

But I want this:

```
0       8
1      16
2     119
3     321
4     333
5       4
6      99
7      30
8     129
9     224
10    355
Name: day, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your code with a minor modification. You have to specify the number of samples.

```
random_days = lambda x: np.random.choice(range(1, 366), len(x), replace=False)
years['day'] = years.groupby('year').transform(random_days)
```

Output:

```
>>> years
    year  day
0      1   18
1      1  300
2      2  154
3      2  355
4      2  311
5      3   18
6      3   14
7      4  160
8      4  304
9      4   67
10     4    6
```

Comment: you nailed it, thanks!, good to know I was on the right track with transform :)

Answer (score 0):

With [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) [*broadcasting*](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) :

```
years["day"] = np.random.choice(366, years.shape[0], False) % 366
​
years["day"] = years.groupby("year").transform(lambda x: np.random.permutation(x))
```

​
Output :

```
print(years)

    year  day
0      1  233
1      1  147
2      2    1
3      2  340
4      2  267
5      3  204
6      3  256
7      4  354
8      4   94
9      4  196
10     4  164
```

Comment: This errors out when the number of years > 366. I need a solution that works when my dataframe is large and the number of years is up in the 1000s.